# Using custom Page Layout for custom team site template

Tags: 2013, page-layout, team-sites

I have created a web template based on Team site. Is it possible to have custom Page Layout for this web template? I have heard that it is not possible to have custom page layout for teams sites. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use page layouts on team site, but you have to activate publishing features on the team site (so basically you could just have used one of the publishing site templates like cms as base for your web template).

I usually base my web templates on sts and then activate the site and web scoped publishing features on it via the onet,xml

Comment: ok, If I activate publishing features does it means that all pages going to be created in pages list and they must be checked in and published before they are accessible??